How should I introduce my characters' powers?
I'm currently trying to write a book about magic. I've planned out how the characters get their powers, but not how the readers can find out about said powers. How and when should I introduce their powers?

Welcome to Writing.SE! Please don't capitalise every single letter, as it makes your posts much harder to read.

I'm sure you have read books and comics about characters with powers and watched movies and tv series characters with powers. How are the powers of the characters introduced there? And why do those solutions not work for you? Please add some more information to your question. As it stands, your question is too general and vague.

From the characters' point of view.
If your characters gain them during the course of the story, then you have the easy task of letting them learn together.  If not -- and you imply not -- you have to ponder how the characters would use them and think about them.
So if your characters can fly, they should either fly for its usefulness, or for fun, or consider whether they should fly, or perhaps worry they might fly by accident before someone they wish to keep this secret from.

As a general rule, if a character has any sort of super-power (including magic), you want to be sure the reader/audience knows unmistakably that magic exists in this world, from Chapter One.
When you read the first book of Harry Potter (Sorcerer's Stone), there is magic occurring in the first scene.
Don't rely on the cover to convey this information; generally in traditional publishing the author doesn't get much control of the cover. Don't just tell the reader that magic exists; there should be a scene in which  magic is used.
That's a general rule I think is important for any beginning writer; anything you want the reader to know should always be conveyed in a scene, never explicitly. Even if Jack is tall, there should be a scene where Jack is doing something that lets the reader know he is tall, do not just tell people Jack is six foot six, find a way to show Jack being six foot six, something a six foot six man can do that an average man could not.
Same with magic. Don't just tell the audience that there is magic, you need to show them there is magic.
In a story where characters get their magical powers, you can't show them being magic from the start, but you can show somebody or something else doing something inexplicable that must be magic. Appearing out of literally nowhere, flying, changing form, or something like that.
If your plan is for them to get magic powers, it is important that the reader knows there is magic in the first 1/8th of the story, which is typically the "inciting incident" in the 3-Act Structure (which you should be following).
The Inciting Incident could very well be their initial exposure to something clearly magical, which they then pursue in the second eighth.
In this case, the 1st eighth would be devoted to showing your characters in their "normal world", without magical powers. Their normal life, their personalities, how they know each other.
Then this chosen group is together when the inciting incident occurs, and in their dealing with that incident, they inadvertently get powers.
The reader finds out about their powers by experiencing the scenes in which  the characters find out about their powers.
End of Act I, Begin Act IIa.
Next is what they aim to do with these powers. Which, of course, should go very wrong, and cause a lot of trouble they don't want.
And so they try to fix that trouble, and make it worse.
What you don't want to do is write a wish fulfillment story. The definition of a hero, in fiction, is basically a character that would literally rather die than give up. They get kicked down, they get beaten, they make wrong choices with terrible consequences, but they keep -- getting -- up. To try again, even to risk their lives, to reach their goal.
Think of Bruce Willis in Die Hard. He's going to save his wife or die trying, and boy howdy does he prove that, again and again and again.
Your reader should be a vicarious member of the group; going along with them, or if one of the group turns out to be the villain, going along with the heroes.
I strongly recommend you review the Three Act Structure, there are diagrams galore, but basically you can find good descriptions that break the story into 8 equal parts; Act I, Act IIa, Act IIb, Act III, and their midpoints. The midpoint of Act I is the "Inciting Incident".
This is by far the most saleable structure for stories.
Good Luck.
